# Filter pandas DataFrame column based on multiple conditions returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble in filtering databased on a multiple conditions.
[dataframe image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN9Nd.png
When I filter it based on multiple condition, I am getting empty DataFrame.

```
user_ID_existing = input("Enter User ID:")
print("Available categories are:\n Vehicle\tGadgets")
user_Category_existing = str(input("Choose from the above category:"))
info = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx")
data = pd.DataFrame(info)
df = data[((data.ID == user_ID_existing) & (data.Category == user_Category_existing))]
print(df)
```

if I replace the variables user_ID_existing and user_Category_existing with values, I am getting the rows. I even tried with numpy and only getting empty dataframe

```
filtered_values = np.where((data['ID'] == user_ID_existing) & (data['Category'].str.contains(user_Category_existing)))
print(filtered_values)
print(data.loc[filtered_values])
```

Comment: Try to use condition something like -
df = data[((data["ID"] == user_ID_existing) & (data["Category"] == user_Category_existing))]

Comment: @RajkumarHajgude Tried this and then also getting empty dataframe only

Answer (score 0):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returs a *string* but since the column `ID` read by pandas has a number dtype, when you filter it by a string, you're then getting an empty dataframe.

You need to use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert the value/ID (entered by the user) to a *number*.

Try this :

```
user_ID_existing = int(input("Enter User ID:"))

print("Available categories are:\n Vehicle\tGadgets")
user_Category_existing = input("Choose from the above category:")

data = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx")

df = data[(data["ID"].eq(user_ID_existing))
          & (data["Category"].eq(user_Category_existing))].copy()

print(df)
```